# Best methods to access an existing object from Web Api Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, katana

I have a selfhosted web api hosted in a WPF application.
The application creates an object to communicate with an external component.
From a Webapi controller i would like to access that existing object and its properties.
What is the best way to achieve this ?
Of course i have already made an attempt with dependency injection. It works but the object is recreated when the web api controller get called.
Should i go for static object ?
Can you give me some hints ?
Thanks in advance.
K.

Comment: Which IoC framework are you using? You might want to look into how the framework lets you handle lifetime scopes

Comment: I am using Unity following this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Comment: In that case you might want to register your object with a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` which will make sure you get the same instance of the object for every request

Comment: Yes indeed, but my object has already been created by the mainviewmodel of the WPF application. I would like to inject that object reference to the web api controller. While specifying ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, the object is recreated again.

Comment: If you are sure the VM is to be responsible for creating the instance, the VM will also have to register the instance with the container. This can be done using the `RegisterInstance` method. Note that this has to be done before the api controller is insantiated (assuming it has a constructor dependency). You may want to post more code if that doesn't work for you

Comment: I made my Main VM class as Singleton and then i am injecting like the following : 
container.RegisterInstance<IMiniBotManager>(MainWindowViewModel.Instance.MyMiniBotManager, (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()));
This time i access the object using o property of the main VM and the object is created only once.
But using a singleton for the main VM is it a good way ?